# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Api::V1::VersionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am building a rails API, and I want to see the data in my browser when I use the appropriate url followed by `.json` or `.xml`. I am getting the following error:

`Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Api::V1::VersionsController`

I set up a `versions_controller.rb` in the path `music-app/app/controllers/api/v1/versions_controller.rb`:

```
class API::V1::VersionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def index
    @versions = Version.all
    respond_with(@versions)
  end

  def show
    @versions = Song.find_by(:id => params[:song_id]).versions
    respond_with(@versions)
  end
end
```

and my routes:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
   get '/versions' => 'versions#index'
   get '/versions/:id' => 'versions#show'
  end
end
```

Am I missing something, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Try ::API::V1::VersionsController, I seem to remember an issue with namespacing this many levels.

Comment: @JamesDullaghan hmm doesn't seem to change. But yes i am sure, namespacing many levels can cause some issues. And see the updated error message that I have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the uppercase of API in the controller that is causing your issues.

Try capitalized

```
class Api::V1::VersionsController < ApplicationController
```